# html, css - 100% div height for single page website on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile

I am trying create a simple single page site that works on mobile. Ideally, I'd like each section of the site to be 100% of the browser height. This is the page:

http://codepen.io/juanp83/pen/EgjBwK

and here's the code:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.one, .three {
  background-color: #666;
}

.two {
  background-color: #222;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--nav-->
<div class="nav"></div>

<!--Section1-->
<div class="section one">
<div class ="bottom"><p>By Juan Portillo</p></div>
</div>

<!--Section2-->
<div class="section two">

</div>

<!--Section3-->
<div class="section three">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works great on my desktop. But I tried it on my iPhone and the first section takes up the entire height of the webpage, not just the height of the browser, so it ends up "hiding" the other sections.

I've done several searches here on stack overflow as well as some other sites but I just can't find a fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
.section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Set the height to your viewport height using vh.

Reference: https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100vh
```

that should do the trick

```
vh = viewport height
```